# Looking for a Movie with Killer Glowing Green Floaties

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv, horror

I can't remember much about this movie (it *might* have been a TV episode) where some sort of glowing green "floaties" (think like purpose-driven gnats) devour people as if by burning them to death. There is even a scene where they get into a car through the ventilation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

Possibly season 1 episode 20 of the x-files "Darkness Falls"

[see if this looks familiar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVTt5fyL_ec)

They get into the car through ventilation, someone could consider the way the victim acts as being burned alive and there is a slight green glow elsewhere in the episode

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark it as accepted!